# SFML Won't Draw Anything?

Tags: c++, sfml, game-loop

I'm used to using SDL for C++ but I heard that SFML is better so I tried it. I tried to render a basic sprite and that didn't work. Then I tried to clear the window to a different colour and that didn't work. It's simple code so what is going on? (Spacing is a little off for some reason, sorry)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"


int main(){

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "It worked");

sf::Texture boxTexture;
boxTexture.loadFromFile("box.png");



while (window.isOpen()){

    window.clear(sf::Color::Blue);

    sf::CircleShape circle;
    circle.setRadius(10);
    circle.setPosition(1, 1);
    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);

    window.draw(circle);

    window.display();

}


return 0;
}
```

All this does is display a white screen... It won't change the background to blue. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How would you know? Both the background and the sprite is blue.

Comment: Because like i said the screen is white... so at least something should be blue @nilo

Comment: Try to put exactly this snippet: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-draw.php

Comment: Then you need to add the event handling.

Comment: Never mind! Fixed it myself... I was being a dunkhoff

Comment: this mark as solved :)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you don't need it, you have to put the event handling loop. From the SFML tutorial page:

> A mistake that people often make is to forget the event loop, simply because they don't yet care about handling events (they use real-time inputs instead). Without an event loop, the window will become unresponsive. It is important to note that the event loop has two roles: in addition to providing events to the user, it gives the window a chance to process its internal events too, which is required so that it can react to move or resize user actions.

You can learn more about [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-window.php#bringing-the-window-to-life)

Hope this helps